# Two components in the same .xaml Grid.Row. When I scroll down, one of them floats, the other scrolls. I need both of them to scroll

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid-layout

I've come accross some .xaml code I need to fix. Currently, it's made of 2 grid components with this layout:

```
<Grid d:SomeDataContext>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView Style="{StaticResource SomeListStyle}" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,80" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <mycontrol:Panel1Control />
        <mycontrol:Panel2Control />
        <mycontrol:Panel3Control />
        <mycontrol:Panel4Control />
        <mycontrol:Panel5Control />
    </ListView>
    <controls:HeaderControlTransparent Grid.Row="0" />
</Grid>
```

When this xaml is interpreted, in run time you get a nice list scroller made up of Panel1, Panel2, etc... On top of that, there's some transparent header aligned to the top of the screen.
In fact, this header is "SO aligned" it doesn't move when scrolling, but floats.
The desired placement is something like:

```
[Header]
[Panel1]
[Panel2]
[Panel3]
[Panel4]
[Panel5]
```

And the desired behaviour when someone scrolls, shoule be the [header] element disappearing from the upper part of the screen as if it was one of the other panels.

```
Desired (not happening)
...     
[Panel3]
[Panel4]
[Panel5]


Undesired (happening)
[Header]
[Panel4]
[Panel5]
```

Currently the header doesn't scroll and it just floats on top of everything, aligned to the top part of the screen, while the panels scroll.

Any hint I should be addressing? I think everything is in order. I can't see why one row of the grid scrolls and the other doesn't.

I'm kind of new to .xaml so, this may also be one of the reasons of my troubles. 
Thanks.

Comment: So just change your ListView to Grid.Row=1, and disable the Vertical/Horizontal Scrolling on the ListView, then just slap it all in a ScrollViewer, and you're done.

Comment: The ScrollViewer did the trick. The Grid.Row=0 (so the overlap) is somewhat intended, so I left it, and the header appears on top of the first panel (which has the space for it). 
BTW, if you change your comment into a proper answer, I'll vote you up.

Answer (score 0):

So may as well add a little to the comment for some additional explanation to future readers and apparently some easy points.

In your example there's two rows (for I guess some other reason) of the `Grid` with both of the children within the same cell. Since the Header control part sits underneath the `ListView` in the DOM then it's rendered logically on top of the underlying ListView.

A ListView already as a `ScrollViewer` built into the control template to nest its items in. However the OP requires elements outside of the controls template to scroll with the items in the ListView.

So by Embedding both the ListView and the Header control in the right order within their own parent ScrollViewer, the desired result can be had of scrolling both bits of content.

e.g. (in pseudo)

```
<Grid>
  <ScrollViewer>
    <objects2/>
  </ScrollViewer>
  <object1/>
</Grid>
```

Would float object 1 over top of objects 2 and keep object 1 stationary while everything else scrolls. However;

```
<ScrollViewer>
   <Grid>
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
       <RowDefinition/>
       <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
     <object1/>
     <objects2 Grid.Row="1"/>
   </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Will scroll all the children keeping their stacked location.

Hope this helps, cheers!